# .Net Core 3.1 Hosting Environment in _Layout.cshtml Error: CS0841: Cannot use local variable 'hostingEnv' before it is declared

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I get the error: CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'hostingEnv' before it is declared.

At the top of my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv
```

Then I get the error with this:

```
        @if (hostingEnv.EnvironmentName == "Development")
        {
            @:<span>In Development</span>
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Matthew Cox, where did you use the if clause? It works well in my project just by using your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try another way to access environment:

```
<environment include="Development">
  <div>The effective tag is: &lt;environment include="Development"&gt;</div>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
  <div>The effective tag is: &lt;environment exclude="Development"&gt;</div>
</environment>
<environment include="Staging,Development,Staging_2">
  <div>
    The effective tag is:
    &lt;environment include="Staging,Development,Staging_2"&gt;
  </div>
</environment>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: How would I use this with an environment called "Test". (I don't see the function IsTest, but I do see IsDevelopment, IsStaging, and IsProduction).
Thanks!